# jQuery second of matched class selector

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery how can I tell if the second "here" div has been clicked?

http://jsfiddle.net/qBZLM/

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image here"></div>
<div class="image here"></div>
<div class="image here"></div>
```

​

Comment: @biziclop This would be better: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBZLM/3/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an option. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbWUL/1/)

```
$('.image.here:eq(1)').click(function(){

    alert('here')
        });​
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".here:eq(1)").click(function(){
    do_something();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.here').eq(1).click()` should work.